# Saving the user session with a single page app using CORS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, cordova, cors

I have read a few articles around the web and even implemented a few, but for the most part following along is quite tedious and gets a bit off track from my base code causing confusion and wasted time.

That said I know I am close with how I have things implemented, I just need access to the `req.user` object which I am pretty sure is stored in a session variable. I want to provide what I have done and figure out how to make that extra push in getting a user login session to stick onto my single page abstracted app (cordova/phonegap).

On the server side I am using (node.js, express.js, and passport.js). I generally will allow express to render the views, but since I am using a CORS abstracted app I don't want to send the template to the client over an AJAX call, so I built the views on the client side, basically at this point regardless of what HTML is rendered I realized I just need to have one AJAX POST call to login the user, to invoke the POST route on my server which authenticates the user.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('body').on('submit', '#logIn', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://mysite.io:3300/login",
            data: formData,
            type: "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               alert('succeeded!');
               console.log('success')
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
              console.log('error')
            }
         }); 

    });

});
```

My question at this point has to do with the passport `req.user` object. In the client side of the CORS app, the session isn't intact it does not seem because the client relies on an api call that only a logged in user can access, I have this route.

```
me: function(req, res) {
    if(req.user) {

        var admin;

        if(req.user.admin === true) {
            admin = true;
        }

        var user = {
            admin          : admin,
            user_id        : req.user.id,
            name           : req.user.local.name,
            email          : req.user.local.email,
        }

        res.json(user);

    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

I also have other routing methods that rely on the `req.user` object. So the initial POST method returns the user object, like the name etc, because I have a routing method that looks like this.

```
//cordova post method
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {
    if (req.user) {
        console.log('is user');
        res.send({ user: req.user }); 
    }
    else
        console.log('is not user');
});
```

Within this method the `req.user` returns true giving me access to the `req.user` object and the template, so when making the ajax POST call I am able to render the user profile. After this or on different routing calls that object is false.

So again my question is how can I save the `req.user` object so I can access it in other methods so that the app knows YES the user is logged in.. obviously that is stored in the session variable, but I am confused upon implementing it?

Comment: So two options I am considering is saving the res.user object into a temporary model and destroying it when the user logs out. Or using access tokens. Using access tokens is probably much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you're handing CORS server-side, but you may want to look into using the [cors middleware](https://github.com/troygoode/node-cors) to make things easier. Either way, you need to make sure you have the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header set to the value of `true`.

For the cors middleware, all you have to do is set `credentials: true` in the cors middleware config. Otherwise you can set the header via `res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');`

You also will need to set `withCredentials` to `true` wherever you do any ajax calls so that the cookies will be sent. For `$.ajax` you would do:

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
}
```

Angular has a similar setting for it's `$http` service.

After that, you should see your `req.user` get auto-populated for authenticated sessions.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I am using the cors-middleware, I am all over the place so I am sure I forgot something. At some point or another I had the `withCredentials` set but I removed it after playing around. Let me try to fiddle with the information you gave me and see if I can make requests as an authenticated user :)

Comment: Okay I think its working, I need to figure out a better way of testing if the cookie is saved, I see it in my console and I was able to make an api request. Will keep testing, ill brb.

Comment: I feel like I am close!! I see the session inside the console, but when I make an ajax request to this route `app.get('/me', cors({credentials: true}), user.me);` I try to return `console.log(req.user)` and it's undefined.. Still looking for mistakes I may have made...

Comment: It's weird because when I login as a specific user the myapp.io/me entered in the browser changes, but when making that request via ajax it's undefined.

Comment: I think I finally got it, I tried using the xhrFields on the GET request and it seems to have worked. I was initially making it only with the POST because I am using backbone.fetch to make my GET requests.

Comment: Sorry for the late check this actually solved it, there was a matter of getting things configured properly and synced up.